# Ways to separate backend and frontend?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, api-design

I want to create project with completely separated back-end (Laravel/Lumen) and front-end (Vue.js). What is most common and best practice to achieve this?

```
1. domain.com + domain.com/api
2. domain.com + domain.com:port
3. domain.com + api.domain.com
4. other?
```

Any of these has any pros and cons?

Comment: I can not see any pros and cons. Just set a standard for you or your team with which you feel good.

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. For example within Laravel you could simply create a `/api` route group. Then again if the configuration and stack are totally different than the front-end you might even run it on another server entirely, in which case it might be easier to host this on a sub-domain. There are dozens more things like this to take into account for both cases, and it all comes down to the context of this entire scenario. I suggest simply doing a lot of research online because this is not something that could easily be answered here.

Comment: If it will be classic REST app, Vue SPA builded files in root / public folder, so available directly through domain.com, Lumen API in separately in api subfolder in subdomains folder, so available through subdomain api.domain.com